# In Excel, how would I insert an empty array into a VSTACK()?

Tags: microsoft-excel

In Excel 365, I am constructing a VSTACK() of a number of arrays, where the inclusion of any given array is conditional. For example, I might have:

```
= VSTACK(if(<condA>),A1#,""),if(<condB>),B1#,""),if(<condC>),C1#,""))
```

That's *nearly* what I want, but it leaves me with a blank cell whenever an array has been omitted because its condition is false. Of course I can always then remove such blanks using a FILTER(), but **is there a (non-VB) way to avoid them being inserted in the first place?** I guess I'd really like a false condition to result in the insertion of a null/empty array instead of a "", but I don't think that's possible.

Comment: Please [edit] the post & share some sample data with us ,,, help to understand then fix it !

Comment: Please check whether the thread is helpful to you, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73932924/vstack-in-excel-used-to-combine-two-sets-of-data-resulting-in-calc-error-if-one

Comment: I think you need to use a recurvise lambda type function like `BYCOL()`

Comment: `=LET(Stack, VSTACK(if(<condA>),A1#,""),if(<condB>),B1#,""),if(<condC>),C1#,"")), Filter(Stack, Stack<>""))` would work